# Dynamically create button in QML

Tags: qt, button, qml

In QML side, receiving one QVariantMap container like CALLS from C++ side. This container having some information (floors, class, variant).

First, Read the how many calls received using count function.

Just for reference (It's not original code), For understanding purpose,

```
 for(int i =0; i < CALSS.count(); i++)
         CreateButton(floors, class, variant);
```

I want to create button component in QML like that.

How to create this dynamic button?

Comment: You might learn enough by reading about "Dynamic QML Object Creation" from Qt documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html and also from the free online Qt QML book: https://www.qt.io/product/qt6/qml-book/ch15-dynamicqml-dynamic-objects

Comment: Use the declarative `Repeater { model: CALSS; delegate: Button { } }` or, even, `ListView { model: CALSS; delegate: Button { } }`.

Comment: Hi @StephenQuan Can we configure each button like after clicked button needs send different parameters (floors, class, variant)

Comment: Of course we can. Where's you're same data describing your use case? Where are the same Button styles?

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, I choose `ListView` because it, by default, allows you to instantiate `Buttons` for every record in your `model`. It places those `Buttons` in a vertical order. It implements scrolling. There's the option of controlling when the `ScrollBar` appears.

With a `ListView.model` you can assign your C++ model. To demonstrate, I've used a mock `QML ListModel`.

For the `ListView.delegate` you can use `DelegateChooser` this will make sure it can instantiate the right `Button` based on a `role` from your `model`. To demonstrate, I made `"floor"`, `"class"`, `"variant"` map to `FloorButton`, `ClassButton` and `VariantButton` respectively.

For demonstration purposes, the implementation of each button type only differs in color.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels
Page {
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement { t: "floor"; n: "Floor 1" }
        ListElement { t: "floor"; n: "Floor 2" }
        ListElement { t: "floor"; n: "Floor 3" }
        ListElement { t: "floor"; n: "Floor 4" }
        ListElement { t: "class"; n: "Class 1" }
        ListElement { t: "class"; n: "Class 2" }
        ListElement { t: "class"; n: "Class 3" }
        ListElement { t: "class"; n: "Class 4" }
        ListElement { t: "variant"; n: "Variant 1" }
        ListElement { t: "variant"; n: "Variant 2" }
        ListElement { t: "variant"; n: "Variant 3" }
        ListElement { t: "variant"; n: "Variant 4" }
        ListElement { t: "floor"; n: "Floor 5" }
        ListElement { t: "floor"; n: "Floor 6" }
        ListElement { t: "class"; n: "Class 5" }
        ListElement { t: "class"; n: "Class 6" }
        ListElement { t: "variant"; n: "Variant 5" }
        ListElement { t: "variant"; n: "Variant 6" }
        ListElement { t: "floor"; n: "Floor 7" }
        ListElement { t: "floor"; n: "Floor 8" }
        ListElement { t: "class"; n: "Class 7" }
        ListElement { t: "class"; n: "Class 8" }
        ListElement { t: "variant"; n: "Variant 7" }
        ListElement { t: "variant"; n: "Variant 8" }
    }
    ListView {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: parent.height * 3 / 4
        width: contentItem.childrenRect.width + 20
        model: listModel
        delegate: DelegateChooser {
            role: "t"
            DelegateChoice { roleValue: "floor"; FloorButton { text: n } }
            DelegateChoice { roleValue: "class"; ClassButton { text: n } }
            DelegateChoice { roleValue: "variant"; VariantButton { text: n } }
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn; width: 20 }
    }
}

// FloorButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Button {
    palette.button: "burlywood"
}

// ClassButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Button {
    palette.button: "lightcyan"
}

// VariantButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Button {
    palette.button: "orange"
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAIfnicrZVNT+MwEIbv/RWjHFnJhcJ+qJygu0hIrHZZpN5dZ2gsHLvrTOlWqP+dcUjSdBOwIshpPPHjN+9MNNb5ynmCW7pda/Uw0gdLMXOWvDPFPi+MXBTib25ylyK/+C2XCE8j4OdGF/QzZKt1eHQ6BVPnm2zY+cNgjpbgCWgKyb1xzifnYDm+CjGcJLAbBEyGAqdDgbO3AWVkUVTALMQxD10g4qELRDx0gYiHR+m1tFQh85dVzEc/FPHSD0X89EMRT91Gfh4KfBla5ohCF4go9BuPqPRDEaWu+a9DgW9DzUcUukBEod94RKUfapR2zYyba9y0Rpy0KnO+EIqPQn/N8Ep6jpsNGeplRnVavCzhCE5hDGfNro1OKZuC4onLu64Jc6EybVJm/qAiUb6HTzA5bpByBPfNV45xKQmn8L2KZplzBfrWZ4eHRzvvSSg5yLYYrXi4l9vm0qyx1e2y05drImdD/fAfG7Swa1U4elTd1rKl7ztq37uqb28et4/uFJ9iLqUXj+hJK8nlbHJMr5zRatvKiQuzkdvilz2vGzY5bn6Q3Wg0HrcrE+7J/67UV2/Y+ovLs1bSIBGKRZlkg4u1N9uNc2lSqbSK9nEqJvyZaittrXJQzY/TcV7aJbLIM2Zbilk=)

Comment: Thanks @Stephan Quan. I will try this one. One doubt I need to define one button, using different variant information specifically update button text.  for example Button(variant1) shows button's text as "Hotel" Button(variant2) shows button's text as "Reception".